# Adding shadow or border to popup window - android

Tags: android, xml, styles, popupwindow, shadow

I have a popupwindow which is connected to a xml content. I want a shadow or a boarder so it gives a better representation  showing that it is a new window. How to I do that in XML or Java?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_popup, null);
PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 650);
pw.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: You should just use an AlertDialog with a custom view

Comment: could you give me an example of how to do it with alertdialog?